# Are Ajax requests CSRF safe?

Tags: ajax, csrf

If my Ajax requests set a X-Requested-With header, can I just skip the CSRF check if this header is present? Can I be sure it cannot be forged (with the user session)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't have a wide open crossdomain.xml (you might have this b/c you host flash content on you site?) or your visitors have old browsers; you should be rather safe. Though I would recommend the use of a "crumb"-token (random value in cookie and the same value in the requests). This b/c flash may set the X-Requested-With and I think that old IE versions allow you to do too (not sure on this one though).

With "can I just skip the CSRF check" I assume you refer to this crumb/token? B/c checking X-Requested-With is a way of checking against CSRF.

Since this header is optional browsers may not always send it, and according to [this page](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Prevention_Measures_That_Do_NOT_Work) they seem to not do it over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we solved the problem with JQuery
http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/implicit-csrf-protection-of-ajax_22.html